# How to make search by related tables in query Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I use Query constuctor in Laravel:

```
 $this->users = User::where(function ($query) 
        use ($request) {

         $query->where('account.email', 'like', '%' . $request->email . '%');

    })->with('account')->get();
```

So, I try to filter rows inside constructor:

```
$query->where('account.email', 'like', '%' . $request->email . '%');
```

But it does not work, because connection of model `account` is below.

How can I use `where` condition inside query constructor by related model `account`?

Answer (score 1):

`whereHas` clause to the rescue. It allows adding query constraints on your relation.

```
$this->users = User::query()
    // Relational query with constraint
    ->whereHas('account', function ($query) use ($request)
    {
        // The query here is scoped to account, 
        // hence you don't need account.email
        $query->where('email', 'like', '%' . $request->email . '%');
    })
    // Still need to eager load 'account' relation
    ->with('account')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query based on related model, you need to use `whereHas('RELATED_MODEL_NAME')`

```
$this->users = User::with('account')->whereHas('account', function($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('email', 'like', '%' . $request->email . '%');
})->get();
```

For more details check [Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships)